I'm having a hard time uninstalling gnome software
Ok, so about a year ago I installed everything on this page https://flathub.org/setup/Ubuntu so please tell me the commands I need to enter to remove everything I installed on that page, I want it all gone. So yeah everything I installed on that page I want removed and deleted from my computer.
I do believe that step number 2 was the gnome software right? Well I tried this command and this is what I got
sudo apt remove gnome-software-center
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gnome-software-center

So it says it can't locate it but gnome software is indeed installed on my PC and I can launch it and use it just fine so I have no idea why it can't be located. I just want everything I installed from that page deleted and gone from my PC. So yeah I'm stumped.
Edit: This is what step number 2 installed (refer to step number 2 here https://flathub.org/setup/Ubuntu ), this is what I want gone from my computer, here I took a screenshot of it, this is what I'm trying to delete from my PC


What s the version of Ubuntu you are using? Why are you trying to remove Gnome?

Your question is based on an error. There is no reference to gnome-software-center in those instructions.

@DavidDE I'm on 22.04LTS. Because I prefer snap store and honestly I can't even remember why I installed gnome software now. VLC is acting funny it's freezing my machine up so I tired to uninstall it, I uninstalled VLC in snap store and yet VLC remained, so I checked gnome software and sure enough in gnome VLC was installed. I'm having a hard time uninstalling VLC and I just want gnome gone. Whatever I installed on that page I want gone. By the way I've always had trouble fully uninstalling VLC. For some reason VLC is a tough cookie to uninstall. I want to uninstall and reinstall VLC.

@OrganicMarble Check out my edit please?

@DavidDE Hey come back here and look at the edit please?

You seem to be having some difficulty reading that page. The package installed in step 2 is gnome-software-plugin-flatpak. If for some reason you want to delete a different package that's fine, but it has nothing to do with those instructions. How about you edit your question and just explain in plain words what you actually want to do?

@OrganicMarble I'm telling you right now that when I went through those steps, that screenshot is what I ended up with, ok. When I went through these steps on this page https://flathub.org/setup/Ubuntu it installed the thing that is in that screenshot, I'm telling the truth. Now whatever that thing is in the screenshot I'd like to get it deleted.

OK, it was installed as a dependency, you didn't have it already. Got it.

You may just want to reinstall and have a fresh version of Ubuntu. In comments, which is not the right place for more info, you now state issues with VLC as well.

This question is similar to: Is there any safe way to remove GNOME Software in 16.04 and install the classic Ubuntu Software Center?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@karel Why did step number 2 install gnome software? Go here, step number 2 literally installed gnome software on my PC https://flathub.org/setup/Ubuntu this is what is causing all the confusion here, it seems step number 2 wasn't supposed to install gnome software (and yet I'm telling you it did). It seems step number 2 was only supposed to install the flatpak plugin but I'm telling you right now it literally installed gnome software on my PC, so this is what is causing all the confusion here because it wasn't supposed to install gnome software but it did. Do you know the answer?

Ubuntu has been shuffling the three software centers Ubuntu Software, Snap Store and GNOME Software like a deck of cards and installing them in Ubuntu for no clear reason. Really you don't need more than one software app in Ubuntu. They finally cleaned up this mess in Ubuntu 24.04.

No,step 2 was sudo apt install gnome-software-plugin-flatpak so maybe you should try sudo apt remove  gnome-software-plugin-flatpak to revert.

sudo apt remove  gnome-software-plugin-flatpak didn't do anything it is still there. Please look up top to my edit, I included a screenshot of what I'm trying to delete.

I found the answer here Is there any safe way to remove GNOME Software in 16.04 and install the classic Ubuntu Software Center?
sudo apt purge gnome-software

This is what worked for me.

Wait...this is about the gnome-software package? Everything in the question says the gnome-software-center package, a different package entirely. It's also unclear why you used remove in the question but purge in the answer. They do slightly different things. I'm glad you found an answer, but how confusing for future readers! Some explanation might help.

@user535733 Dude I'm a newbie when it comes to Linux so thats why I'm here. I'm here to seek advice from the experts. All I know is when I followed the steps on this webpage https://flathub.org/setup/Ubuntu I ended up with the program in that screenshot I provided. So the program in the screenshot is what exactly? I mean I'm a newbie so you tell me whats going on here? Please help me understand this.
